# Is it OK to use GEE insetad of GLM for non-repeated data?

Tags: regression, anova, nonparametric, model, generalized-estimating-equations

I analyse data, that are repeated (pre-post), but I work with change from baseline instead. This is a non-randomized experiment, so I was advised to run this kind of analysis bearing in mind the Lord's paradox and regression to the mean issue when analysing the post values. Anyway.

This gives me a single vector of difference (post-pre) across several groups, defined by the level of factors A (2 levels) and B (2 levels).

I want to run ANOVA on it to find the main and interaction effects, followed by the simple effect analysis.

Unfortunately, the differences aren't normally distributed in any of these groups, which is one of the requirements of the general linear model. Also, these are non homogeneous in variance. However these distributions are quite symmetric, the |skewness| is about 0.1 - 0.3 for N=30-60. There are just a few far distanced observations, but these are perfectly OK, so I cannot threat them as outliers to be removed. All must be used.

I was asked to not run the parametric linear model on it, instead use some non-parametric alternative, like GEE fit or quantile regression, to analyse the output of the model with a series of LR tests via R command anova(model, type="marginal") to get the main and interaction effects.

Yes, we could use a GLM, but nobody has clearly idea what conditional distribution should be used in the GLM, there's no expected mean-variance relationship. The data look "quite symmetric", but the reviewer doesn't agree to use a parametric type 3 ANOVA (data are unbalanced).

Would it be OK to use the GEE fitting method, which doesn't require this assumption on normal residuals as OLS, even if there's no repetition? I assume it will be just ignored. The model with Gaussian conditional response and identity link passed well, gave a bit wider CIs for the means, which is expected, and the estimates are very similar to those from the linear model (differences on the 1 decimal digit with values like 100).

GEE seemed to be a nice alternative to the OLS with the normality assumption bypassed at the cost of wider (robust) CIs. I can use also quantile regression, but this is more about medians - and these medians are almost equal to the means, but this spits with some warnings that the solution may be "non-unique".

How do you find using the GEE without repetitions as a kind of fewer-assumption of the OLS?

I don't want pairwise Wilcoxon. Ideally I would like to test specific contrasts with the LS-means, so the linear model via OLS or GEE would be ideal.

Comment: You should just use a regular OLS with robust standard errors. This is what GEE does anyway. It might be a bit of a challenge to incorporate the robust standard errors in the ANOVA, but it's not impossible. Actually, the `estimatr` package in R makes this straightforward.

Comment: Why didn't I think about that from the first moment! I was so close, but was blind. Thank you! I believe the sandwich package will also help, since I have the var_cov available (I could even calculate it on my own). Yes, I recall the estimatr, I used it once, that's a very good advice. Thank you!